HOW to get offset when selecting event or click +xx more in react-big-calendar?
library: react-big-calendar.
currently i have a customize dialog, and it was placed by offset.
the tricky problem is i can't get offset when clicking +2 more or event with pink bg.
wondering is there a way to get the current offset so that i can display the dialog and show event list correctly
enter image description here
    <DragAndDropCalendar
          components={components}
          defaultDate={defaultDate}
          events={existingTimeSlots}
          localizer={localizer}
          selectable
          onShowMore={(events, date) => {
            console.log("object :>> ", events, date)
            console.log("sowmore")
          }}
          onSelectSlot={handleSelectSlot}
          // TODO: handle select event
          onSelectEvent={(event) => {
            console.log("onSelectEvent", event)
          }}
        />

i can't get event from the onShowMore callback

@steve-cutter-blades pls help
